# MiFare 1K запись данных, Exeption

Tags: c#, nfc

Пытаюсь записать данные на карту MiFare Classic 1K, выдаёт исключение Exeption:Unable to login in sector 2 with key key B.

Считывание из блоков происходит без проблем. Пытаюсь записать 6 цифр (123456). Сам метод SetData() выполняется. Исключение вылетает при попытке записать непосредственно на карту в методе card.Flush()

```
 try
        {
            card?.Dispose();
            card = args.SmartCard.CreateMiFareCard();
            var sector = 2;
            var localCard = card;
            if (emptyCard == true)
            {

                var cardIdentification = await localCard.GetCardInfo();
                byte[] dataForCard = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(id);
                await localCard.SetData(sector, 1, dataForCard);

                var data = await localCard.GetData(sector, 1, 48);
                string hexString = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                {
                    hexString += data[i].ToString();
                }
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format(hexString));
                canChange = true;
                await localCard.Flush();
                MessageBox.Show("удача");


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            PopupMessage("Exception: " + e.Message);
            emptyCard = false;
        }
```